# xcode logout using NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults, logout

I have a logIn button in my app and i am using this code to save the user name in my app using the NS User Defaults:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [defaults setObject:self.usernameField.text forKey:@"UserName"];
                    [defaults synchronize];
```

i want to logout this user and I have been looking for a solution but nothing was helpful. I do not want to use (Parse).

How can I logout from the last user?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remove "UserName" entry from `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Please do not user NSUserDefaults to persist user credentials. Use something like NSURLCredentialStorage instead, it does not store things in plaintext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send defaults a `removeObjectForKey:` message, similar to how you send the `setObject:forKey:` message. This will remove the username from the user defaults, however you will still need to handle the logging out portion since that is app-specific.